# How to solve the total task on "return true to win" in 21 chars

Tags: code-golf, tips, javascript

There is a site called ["Return True to Win"](https://alf.nu/ReturnTrue) with interesting tasks for Javascript programmers. The goal is to find arguments to a given function that force it to return true.

The following is one of the tasks:

```
function total(x) {
  return (x < x) && (x == x) && (x > x);
}
```

The users must find snippets for the value of `x` that cause the function to return true. To test snippets, you call the function with your snippet as the parameter (i.e. `total(<snippet>)`).

I found a 22-character solution:

```
{valueOf:_=>n++%3},n=0
```

Some people found the solution in 21 chars. I can't find out this solution. What is the solution in 21 chars?

Comment: You should link the contest/page the task is taken from.

Comment: https://alf.nu/ReturnTrue

Comment: You can't see the total task without solving previous tasks, You can find solutions on https://gist.github.com/OlegTar/cc79df913cafb3045474578e8ada8a3d

Comment: @Riker Which JS engine are you using? [Here](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9Wmpdckpmfp1CSX5KYo1GhqVDNpaBQlFpSWpSnoFGhYKMAFFJTAzFtbRFsOyDTmquWKzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dA2LC/@qyxJzSVP80q3hbuzxtbVXjWp08W4P/mpr/AQ) is a working link.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood how to run this. I thougth the code was supposed to replace the above code.

Comment: `{valueOf:Math.random}` works from time to time ... but I suspect that would infringe some rule... (or maybe not?)

Comment: Those are decidedly tricky; out of the first 24, I can only answer 14...

Comment: Salty dev note... having a function return Boolean called “total” is like nails on a chalkboard!

Comment: @scunliffe It's probably an adjective like in the algebraic structure [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order). _Total_ here means any two elements of a set are comparable. It's not the bottom line of a restaurant bill. Just my guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## 21 chars

```
{valueOf:n=_=>n=2<<n}
```

---

My original joke, which got downvoted and proposed for deletion:

## 11 chars :)

```
total=_=>!0
```

Test:

```
function total(x) {
  return (x < x) && (x == x) && (x > x);
}
var arg = total=_=>!0
console.log(total(arg))
```

Comment: Good job thinking outside the box, but the challenge is to finish `function total(x) { ... } total(<insert here>)` and have the result of the `total()` call be `true`, so I don't think this will work...

Comment: @ETHproductions `<insert here>` -> `0),(true` :)

Comment: Tried that, and also `0)||(true`. Neither work though, and now I'm totally confused because there's another level where you have to do `0);(!0` or smth similar...

Comment: Your newer solution is amazing, +1 from me!

Answer (score 4):

## Cheaty answer

I've already mentioned it in the comments, but it was not tested. It is now. You'll have to keep submitting it until it works.

```js
{valueOf:Math.random}
```

#### Demo

```js
function total(x) {
  return (x < x) && (x == x) && (x > x);
}

for(i = 1; !total({valueOf:Math.random}); i++);

console.log('Returned true after ' + i + ' iteration(s)')
```

Comment: Could you explain more about how this works? I just cannot understand how the `x == x` became true if x is chosen randomly every time.

Comment: @tsh The trick is that `valueOf` is not invoked when the equality test is processed. On the other hand, comparison operators expect primitive values, which forces `valueOf` to be called. [Here is a test](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f@/wra6LDGnNNU/zSre1i45P684PydVLyc/XUM9OTEnR6EkXwEqr65Zy4UiH5JaXKKgbKiuyVWhYGurUIFN1ggsa4Nd0hgsaadQ8f8/AA) showing that.

Comment: I got a high score of <s>15</s>16 iterations!!!

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Come on, you can do better than that! Insert coin and play again!